# How to port application glassfish to tomcat?

Tags: rest, tomcat, glassfish

I have rest services using net beans and glass fish application server. How can i deploy same war file on tomcat web server.
I have tried to deploy same war on tomcat but it is giving 404

Comment: 404 error code indicates "NOT FOUND". That means your war file is not there in the web apps folder in tomcat. That is why it is throwing you the 404 error status code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the procedure.

1. Copy the war file
2. Go to the folder named `Tomcat` (Path to your tomcat installation)
3. Then select `webapps` folder
4. Paste the war file into the `webapps` folder
5. Now open a web browser and type

   http://localhost/YOUR_WAR_FILE_NAME

NOTE : I assume that you run tomcat on the default port which is `8080` plus your `tomcat` server is up and running.

Comment: Thanks Duilth , In my war all rest services are working fine in glass fish but on tomcat they are not working

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Did you check Tomcat`s webapps folder ?

Comment: yes . default index.html is working as expected. but problem in rest urls

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be in web app descriptor. In Glassfish it is glassfish-web.xml but in Tomcat it is web.xml.

You should remove first and add second.